# pylint generates r:redefined-variable-type when using enums?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I'm using python 3.4.2 and pylint 1.5.2. Pylint is printing a r:redefined-variable-type warning when I use a variable of type enum. The following script demonstrates the problem:

EnumRepro.py:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    Value1 = 1
Value2 = 2

myEnum = MyEnum.Value1
print("my enum is {}".format(myEnum))

# Huh? this line generates
# warning R0204: Redefinition of myEnum type from EnumRepro.MyEnum.Value1 to 
# EnumRepro.MyEnum.Value2 [R:redefined-variable-type]
myEnum = MyEnum.Value2 # this generates 
print("my enum is {}".format(myEnum))
```

any suggestions? currently, I'm just spot-disabling R0204 whenever I use enums, but that's not ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with pylint (enums and R0204 in general). Multiple issues are reported, e.g. https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/781

Thus, spot- or completely disabling R0204 for the moment is fine.